# ECC Certificates not working in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I'm attempting to configure HAProxy to serve an RSA or ECC certificate depending on the client's browser. I initially am trying to get ECC certificates configured, and I noticed that the latest version of Chrome does not support them. Wondering if anyone else is having this problem? I am using OS X 10.11.4 with the following versions:

- Chrome (50.0.2661.94) (64-bit) **[doesn't work]**
- Firefox (46.0) (64-bit) **[works]**
- Safari (9.1 11601.5.17.1) (64-bit) **[works]**
- cURL (7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5) **[works]**

The cURL command I call via `curl --ciphers ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_sha --ssl --head --tlsv1.2 https://<url>` and it returns 200 OK.

And I am using Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS on the server side with the following versions:

```
[root@haproxy-server]: /etc/haproxy # haproxy -vv
HA-Proxy version 1.6.4 2016/03/13
Copyright 2000-2016 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>

Build options :
  TARGET  = linux2628
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
  OPTIONS = USE_ZLIB=1 USE_REGPARM=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_PCRE=1

Default settings :
  maxconn = 2000, bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with zlib version : 1.2.8
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports prefer-server-ciphers : yes
Built with PCRE version : 8.38 2015-11-23
PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
Built with Lua version : Lua 5.3.1
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.
```

Here's the screenshot of the exact problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp88t.jpg

Here's the screenshot of the same website with Safari: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaAkZ.jpg

And finally, my `haproxy.cfg` file:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    chroot  /var/lib/haproxy
    daemon
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock level admin
    maxconn 15000
    spread-checks 5
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param   2048
    tune.ssl.maxrecord  1400
    tune.idletimer  1000

    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256

    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11 no-tls-tickets

    ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256

    ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11 no-tls-tickets

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    retries 3
    balance roundrobin
    hash-type map-based
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option  forwardfor
    option  http-server-close
    option  redispatch
    option  abortonclose
    log-format %ci:%cp\ [%t]\ %ft\ %b/%s\ %Tq/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Tt\ %ST\ %B\ %CC\ %CS\ %tsc\ %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq\ %hr\ %hs\ %{+Q}r
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          30s
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http-frontend
    bind    *:80 accept-proxy
    reqadd  X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    use_backend %[req.hdr(host),lower,map_sub(/etc/haproxy/backend.map,test-backend)]

frontend https-frontend
    bind    *:443 accept-proxy ssl crt /etc/ssl/pem/ecc alpn http/1.1
    log-format %ci:%cp\ [%t]\ %ft\ %b/%s\ %Tq/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Tt\ %ST\ %B\ %CC\ %CS\ %tsc\ %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq\ %hr\ %hs\ %{+Q}r\ ssl_version:%sslv\ ssl_cipher:%sslc\ %[ssl_fc_sni]\ %[ssl_fc_npn]
    rspadd  Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=31536000;\ includeSubdomains;\ preload
    rspadd  X-Frame-Options:\ DENY
    reqadd  X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    use_backend %[req.hdr(host),lower,map_sub(/etc/haproxy/backend.map,test-backend)]

backend test-backend
    balance leastconn
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    server test-server 10.10.10.40:80 check
```

Comment: You have only very few ciphers configured and browsers differ in which ciphers they support. I recommend to use instead the [settings recommended by Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_configurations). As for your current configuration: please check against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) what your server actually shows as supported and then check your Chrome browser against [SSLLabs client test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html). Then see if you find an overlap of ciphers.

Comment: Could you post the URL to your server if it's online?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww: I believe I need a certain level of reputation to move a question around? Is it possible for you to initiate a move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that only the following two cipher suite are supported by your web server:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

**I suppose that missing some cipher suite (at least `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`) is the reason of your problem.**

The cipher suite `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` **must** be supported in TLS 1.2 (see [the section 9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-9) Mandatory Cipher Suites or RFC5246). In the same way I would you recommend to see forward and to include protocols

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

and the suites

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

are strictly recommended too. See [TLS 1.3 specification](https://tlswg.github.io/tls13-spec/#rfc.section.8). You use Nginx  web server, which should support `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` and `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256`, which are very good because of combination the security and the performance. I'd recommend you to include all the Cipher Suites.

I'd recommend you additionally to use or at least to examine carefully the recommendation of Nginx setting for [modern](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=nginx-1.10.0&openssl=1.0.2g&hsts=yes&profile=modern) or [intermediate](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=nginx-1.9.5&openssl=1.0.2g&hsts=yes&profile=intermediate) web browsers by Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator. You can read more about the suites [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS).

Comment: Would the algorithm of the private key also be a factor? I know for certain Chrome doesn't support `secp521r1`

Comment: @ScottCrooks: It's correct, but [the SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=httptest.vacasait.com&s=52.27.183.7&hideResults=on&latest) shows that one use currently `secp256r1`. The exact choice depend on requirements. One can specify `secp521r1,secp384r1,secp256r1` for example if one want. The problem is `secp521r1` is much slowly as `secp384r1` and `secp384r1` is slowly as `secp256r1`. The choice `secp521r1,secp384r1,secp256r1` could be good for tests, but I'm not sure that it would be good for production.

Comment: I think you are referring to one of the keys in the CA chain. The certificate we're using actually says `EC 521 bit`. Either way, thank you for the advice on the ciphers :)

Comment: @ScottCrooks: Do you tried that the problem is solved by adding missing cipher sites? You use EC521 **only for signing of the certificate**. The suite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 **uses another cipher suite** sec256r1 currently for TLS. Probably you Chrome can't validate the certificate, but the system which can validate the certificate use sec256r1 for TLS

Comment: @ScottCrooks: By the way I recommend you to take a look on TLS configuration of https://suche.org/ and it's test https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=suche.org

Comment: Yes, I put in the ciphers you recommended. See the latest config here: https://gist.github.com/sc250024/0479e6734580afc30d45b0d0e01e0194. Still getting the same problem.

Comment: Do you replaced the SSL Certificate to another one which is signed with secp384r1? It's strange that SSL test detect the server as Nginx? Do you posted correct URL? I don't use haproxy myself. Do you used/compared with mozilla configurator [here](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy-1.5.14&openssl=1.0.1e&hsts=yes&profile=intermediate)? I though that haproxy don't support HTTP/2 (see https://istlsfastyet.com/#server-performance). What web server you use currently? Is it online and is the URL to `httptest` server really correct URL to your test server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110674/discussion-between-scott-crooks-and-oleg).

Comment: What is your question? What you find strange in the SSL configuration of suche.org? It uses certificate with elliptic curve instead of more common used RSA key. Under https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=suche.org you can see the report. You can see that it uses EC 384 bits certificate, which gives the largest security, but its slow.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is not in the right seciton of StackExchange (sorry!) but I wanted to post a potential solution. I think the problem is the elliptic curves support in Chrome vs. Firefox vs. Safari. From the SSLLabs website:

[Safari 9 / OS X 10.11](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Safari&version=9&platform=OS%20X%2010.11): secp256r1,  secp384r1,  secp521r1

[Firefox 44 / OS X](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Firefox&version=44&platform=OS%20X): secp256r1,  secp384r1,  secp521r1

[Chrome 48 / OS X](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Chrome&version=48&platform=OS%20X):  secp256r1,  secp384r1

The problem is the private key for the ECC certificate I was testing was generated with `secp521r1` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaVU9.jpg), which the latest version of Chrome on OS X 10.11 doesn't support.

See this issue: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100991/why-is-secp521r1-no-longer-supported-in-chrome-others